# Obtener href en maps Javascript | jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, map

Éste es mi código (también disponible en [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pan1Lfx/6/)):

```js
function loadminuatura() {
  var images = $(".fileThumb").find('img').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')
  });
  var array = images;
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    $("#repositorio").append('<a href="' + images[i] + '"><img src="' + images[i] + '" /></a>');
  }
}

loadminuatura();
```

```css
.fileThumb {
  margin: 50px;
  position: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="repositorio"></div>
<hr>
<a class="fileThumb" target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/koaTwPt"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/koaTwPt.jpg"></a>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://i.imgur.com/EDfFF8G"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EDfFF8G.jpg"></a>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://i.imgur.com/p2a015Z"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/p2a015Z.png"></a>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://i.imgur.com/G8ZFdYC.png"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/G8ZFdYC.gif"></a>
```

Resulta que de una lista de imágenes, recorro todos los "A" con la clase `fileThumb` y quiero obtener el href y el src de la imagen que está dentro del A, y ponerlo en el `div` repositorio que está arriba.

El tema es que al recorrer solo obtengo el SRC y no el HREF. Y ahí es donde busco ayuda.

```
<a href="'+images[i]+'">
```

Ahí quiero el link del A no el SRC de la imagen.

Comment: Por favor, introduce el código directamente en tu pregunta.

Comment: No queda muy claro qué es lo que quieres obtener o por qué te falla el código que ya tienes. Deberías incluir una mejor descripción del problema para que sea más fácil ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no te estás quedando con los `<a>`, sino con los `<img>`, y el href es un atributo de los tag `<a>`. Te pongo una solución que asume que hay una y sólo una imagen por enlace (no hace muchas comprobaciones, pero así creo que queda más claro cómo solucionar tu problema)

```js
function loadMiniatura() {
  let anchors=$("a.fileThumb");
  let anchorsHrefs=anchors.map(function() {
     return $(this).attr('href');
  });
  let imageSrcs = anchors.find('img').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('src')
  });
  
  for (var i = 0; i < anchorsHrefs.length; i++) {
    $("#repositorio").append('<a href="' + anchorsHrefs[i] + '"><img src="' + imageSrcs[i] + '" /></a>');
  }
}

loadMiniatura();
```

```css
.fileThumb {
  margin: 50px;
  position: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="repositorio"></div>
<hr>
<a class="fileThumb" target="_blank" href="https://i.imgur.com/koaTwPt"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/koaTwPt.jpg"></a>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://i.imgur.com/EDfFF8G"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/EDfFF8G.jpg"></a>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://i.imgur.com/p2a015Z"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/p2a015Z.png"></a>
<a class="fileThumb" href="https://i.imgur.com/G8ZFdYC.png"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/G8ZFdYC.gif"></a>
```

Comment: desconocía el contenido de let, **Gracias** ha funcionado el código.

Comment: @normalito1212 Pues es muy útil y desde IE11 todos los navegadores lo soportan, te aconsejo que lo vayas mirando ;)

Comment: @Javi por defecto ya no uso `var` para nada, uso let para declarar cualquier variable. Se hace más cercano a la forma de declarar variables de otros lenguajes y me ahorra algunos quebraderos de cabeza